# How do I get parameter names for both getter and setter when using TypeLibConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, com, typelib

I need to parse a type library and analyze parameters of each method of each interface. So I use `TypeLibConverter.ConvertTypeLibToAssembly()` to convert `ITypeLib` into an `AssemblyBuilder` and call `GetTypes()` to access the types in the interop. I pass `None` as flags into `ConvertTypeLibToAssembly()`.

Now in the typelib a had a dual interface with an `int` property `Magic`:

```
[propget, id( 1 )]
HRESULT Magic( [out, retval] int* Result );
[propput, id( 1 )]
HRESULT Magic( [in] int NewValue );
```

and in the resulting assembly the matching interface has two methods - one is

```
Int32 get_Magic()
```

and the other is

```
Void set_Magic( Int32 Result )
```

You see - the getter now has no parameters and so I can't get to the original parameter name and the setter simply has wrong name (one which the getter had).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's entirely normal, it is not an indexed property so has no arguments.  The standard C# name for the setter's argument is "value".

Comment: @HansPassant: Okay, but I'd still be happy to get to the original names in the typelib.